# Strange error when closing Vim

Tags: error, quit, viminfo

I'm victim of a witchcraft. Likely my own.

There's no Vim session open, based on the empty output of `pidof vim` and can open a new or existing file just fine. When I quit it with `:q`, however, I see to errors flashing on screen, but Vim closes nonetheless. Recording a GIF and spitting in frame I could see the two errors:

```
E929: Too many viminfo temp files, like /home/enrico/.viminfa.tmp!
E138: Cannot write viminfo file /home/enrico/.viminfa.tmp!
```

Well, this file, `.viminfa.tmp` does exist, but it's 0 bytes and I've not intentionally created it.

Furthermore, based on the comments I've verified that the error

- occurs if I simply empty my `~/.vimrc` file,
- does not occur if I open Vim via `vim -u NONE`,
- occurs if I open Vim via `vim -u NONE -N`.

Where does it come from? What have I broken?

Comment: Look like a good candidate for [How do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841).

Comment: There is an option (-V maybe) to record a log

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `~/.viminf*.tmp` files? See `:help E929`, which says: *"When you get error E929: Too many viminfo temp files check that no old temp files were left behind (e.g. `~/.viminf*`) and that you can write in the directory of the `.viminfo` file."*

Comment: @filbranden, yes, it does, and there where several of them (probably more than 10). Where could they come from?

Comment: `:help viminfo-file-name`; basically, if you're using `-i`, `n` in `viminfo`, `viminfofile`, or the manual viminfo commands. (This could also be the result of a plugin, alas)

Comment: What _I'm using_ is in my vimrc, right? If so, how can the behavior I observe with `vim -u NONE -N` depend on what I'm using?